# Apple Watch Notification Actions not working when app is terminated

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

I'm running into a weird situation where my notification actions that I perform on the Watch is not doing anything after the app is terminated (Double tap home button and swiping up on app). The actions that I'm doing will be reflected on the server so I know if something occurred or not. However if I do the same action on my phone's notification, while the app is terminated, the action would actually be performed in the app. Here's a better detail of the flow I'm testing:

**App is dead (Terminated):**

- Gets notification from watch while phone is locked, perform an action -> nothing
- Gets notification on phone's lock screen, perform an action -> action works
- Gets notification from phone as phone is active/unlocked, perform an action -> action works

**However this works while app is dead:**

- Gets notification on phone's lock screen, perform an action -> action works
- THEN get another notification on watch, perform an action -> action now **works**

**If App is not dead:**

- Gets notification from watch while phone is locked, perform an action -> action works

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "app is dead". Do you mean that the app was suspended and later terminated during the course of normal interaction with the device (e.g. tapped the home button to leave app and then proceeded to use other apps), or that you double-tapped the home button and explicitly killed the app by swiping up on the app?

Comment: Hey Rob, it means the app is terminated (Tapped the home button twice and swipe up the app)

Comment: When you manually kill an app like that, it doesn't always respond to events like it would if it was naturally suspended and terminated by the OS. I'd suggest trying to let the app terminate on its own and see if the behavior changes. You can either hit the home button to suspend it and then run other apps until it is jettisoned by the OS or I sometimes add a debugging button that does an `exit(0)` or one that manually crashes app (obviously not for production use, tho!).